# Showing that a graph doesn't contain a Hamiltonian ccle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

In the article [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365155/showing-that-no-hamilton-circuit-exists)

it says that `A Hamilton circuit cannot contain a smaller circuit within it.`  ?
What is meant by this?
I thought this meant that for example if it's a graph on 10 vertices then it can't have a 3-cycle .But $K_5$ has a 3-cycle and is Hamiltonian. So what exactly is meant by  **cannot contain a smaller circuit within**

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that there is no proper subgraph of a Hamiltonian circuit for a graph $G$ that is also a Hamiltonian circuit for $G$, which is trivially true.